# SQL Select and UPDATE where there are multiple columns and should choose one line

Tags: php, mysql

In SQL server is it possible to insert data where there are different usernames and I have to chose a particular username and under that I have to input the answer column as true for that username only.

This is the query I tried -

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET Answer = Truee FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Username='$username') WHERE Answer = 0";
```

This is shown as an error in my PHP page.

Comment: Please include the error you're facing in the question

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with phpmyadmin. phpmyadmin is a management interface, NOT a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `FROM` in an `UPDATE`. You shouldn't need to do the separate select.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET Answer = True WHERE Username='$username' AND  Answer = 0";
```